# Finding periodicity in discrete events II - missions to Mars

Tags: time-series, periodic, periodogram, time-of-arrival

Per the Space Exploration SE question [Are launch windows to Mars avoided if they result in landings during dust storm season?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50045/12102) the synodic period of the relationship between the motion of Earth and Mars in their orbits with the approximation that they are circular and periodic is given by the following:

> Launches to Mars happen each Earth-Mars [synodic period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period#Examples_of_sidereal_and_synodic_periods):
>
> $$T_{syn} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{T_<} - \frac{1}{T_>}} = \frac{T_< T_>}{T_> - T_<}$$
>
> With $T_>, T_<$ of 1.881 and 1.0 years that's about 2.14 years.

So about every 2.14 years there's an opportunity to launch with a local minimum of [delta-v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) required.

I went to Wikipedia's [List of missions to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_Mars) and skipped the flybys to other bodies that only used Mars as a gravitational assist, and kept 45 that were destined for Mars.

So I have a list of 45 events in time, and I'd like to know the likelihood that there is an underlying periodicity $T$.

Below is the results of my Python script. I can verify a clustering both visually in the first 2D modulo plot, and by the peak in the "inter-arrival" time histogram from [this answer to *Finding periodicity in discrete events*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/55971/25659)

But I'm basically just trying stuff here. Is there:

1. A formal way to do this kind of an analysis, with perhaps a well-defined likelihood or probability distribution for an underlying periodicity $T$?
2. Is there a nice python package that will do it?

[image: looking for the underlying periodicity in launch dates for missions to Mars]

Script:

```
info = """30 July 2020
23 July 2020
19 July 2020
5 May 2018
14 March 2016
18 November 2013
5 November 2013
26 November 2011
4 August 2007
12 August 2005
8 July 2003
10 June 2003
2 June 2003
7 April 2001
3 January 1999
11 December 1998
4 December 1996
16 November 1996
7 November 1996
25 September 1992
12 July 1988
7 July 1988
9 September 1975
20 August 1975
9 August 1973
5 August 1973
25 July 1973
21 July 1973
30 May 1971
28 May 1971
19 May 1971
10 May 1971
9 May 1971
2 April 1969
27 March 1969
27 March 1969
25 February 1969
30 November 1964
28 November 1964
5 November 1964
4 November 1962
1 November 1962
24 October 1962
14 October 1960
10 October 1960""" # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_Mars

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar, datetime
# from scipy.signal import periodogram, lombscargle # no, not these


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418092/3904031
d = {month: index for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month}

lines = info.splitlines()
dates = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
dates = [(int(a), int(d[b[:3]]), int(c))[::-1] for a, b, c in dates]

datetimes = [datetime.datetime(*date) for date in dates]

seconds = np.array([datetime.timestamp() for datetime in datetimes])

years = seconds / (365.25 * 24 * 3600) # "Julian years"

plt.plot(years)
plt.show()

mods = np.linspace(0.5, 5, 251)
results = np.array([np.mod(years, mod) for mod in mods])

# inter-arrival times https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/55971/25659
yearz = (years[:, None] - years).flatten()

if True:
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    for mod, dots in zip(mods, results):
        ax1.plot(mod * np.ones_like(dots), dots, '.k', ms=1)
    a, b = np.histogram(yearz, bins=mods)
    ax2.plot(b[1:], a)
    ax2.set_xlabel('modulo (years)')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: see also "[Have you considered using autocorrelation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2598899/3904031)" in Stack Overflow

Comment: You could ask at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) in the ["seasonality" tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasonality). Much of that is about how to treat *known* seasonality in time series (if we have daily data, we often know there is a seasonal frequency of 7, i.e., intra-weekly seasonality), but there are a few threads about how to *detect* the length of seasonality, e.g., [Automatic detection of seasonality on a time-series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/500796/1352). I don't know whether the pointer in my answer would work in this case, though...

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks! I posted a link in the main chat room there, but that's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: ... and your chat post there is what brought me here, thank you for drawing our attention that way!

Answer (score 1):

In radar systems, this problem sounds like **pulse repetition interval (PRI)** estimation.

[Many](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD1102556.pdf) [techniques](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9146998) [have](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Probability-and-Distribution-in-Time-of-Pulse-in-Perkins/4c10139d8d8b18bf1ff4b8722f648051ddf30a43) [been](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/490557) [tried](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/845217).

Comment: @uhoh I'd start with the first one. My main aim in the answer was to give the buzzwords to help in the search.

Comment: Yes, first one is immediately quite interesting/helpful, *thanks!*